# NullPointerException while reading content of BufferedReader although it's not empty

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader, getresource

I get a NullPointerException everytime I try to obtain the content of my BufferedReader, when I run the project that is already packed in jar. When it runs inside of IDE (IntelliJ) there's no any problem. I have already checked all previous InputStreams, they seem to be all right. Have you maybe some tipp? Thank you in advance!

```
String pathToFontDir = "/fonts/Open_Sans";
GraphicsEnvironment localGE = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
final InputStream is = Session.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToFontDir);
if(is != null){

        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        List fonts = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()); //throws NullPointerException
        if(fonts.size() > 0){
            for(Object font: fonts){
                InputStream fis = loader.getResourceAsStream(pathToFontDir + "/" + font);
                localGE.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fis));
            }
        } else{
            throw new IOException("Der angegebene Ordner enthält keine Schriftdateien!");
        }
    }
```

I also tried just to check, wheather my BufferedReader contains anything, but it throwed an exception again without returning any line:

```
        String fontName;
        while((fontName = br.readLine()) != null) //throws NPE as well
            System.out.println(fontName);
```

The stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
>       at main.java.backend.Session.importFontResource(Session.java:137)
>       at main.java.backend.Session.main(Session.java:180)

Comment: Are you certain that required files are copied into the JAR file?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I have checked it one more time.

Comment: So, essentially you are trying to read the `Open_Sans` **file**, right? And this is what fails?

Comment: Well, yes and no, because there's no problem with the InputStream and InputStreamReader, my console shows that they exist, even the BufferedReader exists, but I can't get anything from it. It throws NPE while calling BR.lines().collect() or BR.readLine()

Comment: So it seems as if the directory Open_Sans would exist in my JAR, but would be empty, however it' not.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. I exported a jar file from Eclipse and when I run the code from your question and do `System.err.println(fonts)` I get the lines of the `Open_Sans` file as an array. You might want to do the same - eliminate all unnecessary code and print the `fonts` variable. Then check the contents of your jar file with `unzip`.

Comment: Ahem, `So it seems as if the directory Open_Sans` - thats why I said **file**. Now, is Open_Sans a **directory** or a **file**? You can not read directory contents with the code from your question

Comment: it's a directory with all Open Sans fonts inside

Comment: And you say it works in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, for sure, exactly the same code! Essentially I'm trying here to automate the font import from a folder, so that I don't have to use getResourceAsStream() for every single font.

Comment: Post the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read a resource directory as such. As there is no *easy* provision in standard java, make a "directory" listing in a resource file, and read that.
Keep it conventional.

For the "uneasy" solution: http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You open an InputStream for resource `/fonts/Open_Sans`.

When run in the IDE that resource is a directory. Seems - I did not know that - that it returns a list of all files in that directory.

When you run the code packaged in a jar, the resource points to a directory entry in the Jar file. The InputStream for that resource is not null, but when you start to read from it, a NPE is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
```

(The inputstream which you obtain from `getResourceAsStream` is a `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream` which extends `FilterInputStream` and it does not sanitize its constructor parameter which causes the NPE later on).

Comment: +1 - `Seems - I did not know that - that it returns a list of all files in that directory.` Me not either ... was quite surprised when I tried it ...

Comment: Yeah you're totally right, I just took a look into the stack trace of my exception and relized that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider opening the stream some other way. When I want a JAR or classpath to read from itself, I use this chain:

```
File classpathBase = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

Once you have that, it's either a Jar File or a directory. From there, you can read the resource using some method along the lines of this one:

```
String resourceName = "/fonts/Open_Sans";
InputStream in;
JarFile jarFile = null;
if (classpathBase.isDirectory()){
   in = new FileInputStream(classPathBase.getPath() + resourceName);
} else {
   jarFile = new JarFile(file);
   JarEntry entry = jarFile.getEntry(resourceName);
   in = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
}
// read from in.read()
in.close();
if (jarFile != null){
    jarFile.close();
}
```